# How can you analyze a Prolog formula?

Tags: prolog, operators, custom-operator

I'm learning how to define custom operators in **Prolog**, but the second exercise on the first page seems a bit complicated for me.

> Given a formula analyze if it's correct.
>
> E.g. : if you define operators: **op1** and **op2**, and variables: **a, b, c** one input to verify would be:

```
?- formula(op1 a op2 b).
```

> And based on how you've defined the operators it should say **true** or **false**.

I've got absolutely no clue how to approach this, because even the **op1 a op2 b** part scares me. I don't know how I can extract the operators and variables from that, and I don't even know if that's the way to go.
Any help is appreciated!

*edit:* My operators specifications are:

```
:- op(630, xfy, op1). 

:- op(610, fy, op2).
```

Comment: and what does the first exercise say? have you done it? before we can talk about analyzing, have you defined the operators yet? in any case, try `write_canonical( 1+2+3 ).` and `1+2+3 =.. X .` at the prompt. does it give you any ideas? :)

Comment: Yes. The first exercise shows how to declare on operator. Declaring an operator is just 1 line of code
```prolog
:- op(630, xfy, op1).
:- op(610, fy, op2).
```

Comment: I don't think that you should define what the operator does exactly for this exercise. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: what it does, no, but what it is, you must. otherwise it's not interpreted as an operator but a regular Prolog atom. Do you understand what `xfy` means, in the `op1` specification? in `xfy`, what letter stands for the operator? how many operands does `op1` expect? and `op2`? what happens when you enter `write_canonical( op1 a op2 b ).` at your Prolog prompt? and `write_canonical( op2 b ).`?

Comment: op2 should be infix, while op1 prefix, otherwise how could be the formula parsed? You coded the other way round...

Comment: @CapelliC the post says "analyze [whether] it's correct" so failure is an option. :)

Comment: @WillNess: of course :). Your comments were more instructive, but OP was in a hurry for help, and his code doesn't compile - I think ...

Comment: @CapelliC there *is* no code... :) well, the movie said there's no spoon, but here there really is no code, for the `formula/1` predicate. so of course it doesn't compile. :) but if there was a code, it'd be OK for a call to it to fail, "returning" `false`, indicating that the expression is not a valid one..... wait. hmm. it'd cause an error before the predicate could even have a chance to work on analyzing it. So I don't really know whether / how could such a predicate be written, *at all !!!* Do you? (looks like an advanced problem; or am I missing something?).

Comment: @WillNess: well, there is code, in OP' 2^ comment. But the query `?- formula(...).` should give error. Better not to steer discussion into generalized parsing, to avoid needless confusion...